# How can I programmatically call the same validator that runs on a @RequestMethod method with a @Valid parameter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I have a class with hibernate's validation annotation on some fields (such as `@NotNull` and `@Size(min = 4, max = 50)`, etc...)

```
public class MyClass {

    Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    String machineName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    String humanName;

    // Getters, setters, etc…
}
```

I also have a custom controller that acts as a JSON API, and a JSON deserializer that creates MyClass objects when API methods are called. In my custom controller I have a method to create a new object of that type:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public long createMyObject(@RequestBody @Valid MyClass newObj) {
    // Create the object in the database
    return newObj.getId();
}
```

and another method that updates an existing object

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateMyObject(@RequestBody MyClass updatedObj) {
    MyClass existingObj = // Get existing obj from DB by updatedObj.getId();

    // Do some secondary validation, such as making sure that a specific
    // field remains unchanged compared to the existing instance
    if (existingObj.getMachineName() != null && 
            !existingObj.getMachineName().equals(updatedObj.getMachineName())) {
        throw new CannotChangeMachineNameException();
    }
    else {
        updatedObj.setMachineName(existingObj.getMachineName());
    }

    // [HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE MAGIC TO HAPPEN]

    // Save updatedObj to the database
}
```

While I can use `@Valid` in `createMyObject`, I cannot use it in `updateMyObject` because our API implementation requires that machineName remains unchanged - users can call the API with a JSON object that either excludes machineName entirely or populate it with the same value that exists in the database.*

Before saving the updated object to the database I want to call the same validator that having the @Valid annotation would cause to be called. How can I find this validator and use it?

Comment: I think you can use validation groups.  Have all the validations other than the `@NotNull` on `machineName` (or a custom validator that compares the old and new name) be in the default group, and have the remaining validator be in the `Update` group.  Use both groups in the `updateMyObject` method. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#d0e2595

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing says you need to use @Valid in your controller methods only. Why not make a validation method that accepts a parameter you annotate as @Valid, then just return that same parameter.

Like this:

```
public Book validateBook(@Valid Book book) {
   return book;
}
```

Looks like an alternative would be to use Hibernate's validation package. [Here's it's documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/).

Basically, you get a `Validator` from a `ValidationFactory`, and then use the validator like this:

```
 @Test
    public void manufacturerIsNull() {
        Car car = new Car(null, "DD-AB-123", 4);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations =
            validator.validate(car);

        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        assertEquals("may not be null", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This lead me close enough to the answer - the first method didn't work, I did something similar to the second method: Set<ConstraintViolation<MyClass>> errors = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(updatedObj); // I got to this from the documentation you pointed

Comment: does the validateBook method throw any exceptions? what if validation fails?

Comment: the first method doesn't initiate any validation. or am I missing something?

Comment: @Happy most probably you invoke the method from the same class so the validation method doesn't get proxied