# @Email hibernate validator annotation not working in JSF 2 Bean

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, managed-bean, hibernate-validator

I have a JSF 2 application and I cannot make work a @Email validation on a JSF ManagedBean attribute.

This is my stack:

- Glassfish 3.1.1
- Mojarra 2.2.9 / JSF 2.2

I've checked in my web-inf/class I have these libraries as recomended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545231/notnull-notblank-and-notempty-bean-validation-does-not-work-in-jsf):

- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA
- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.2.Final

My code:

```
<h:body>
<!-- <h:log id="log" /> -->
<h:messages globalOnly="true" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />

<h:form id="form">
    <f:validateBean>
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Enter your email: " />
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{userEditBean.email}" />
        <h:message for="email" />

        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Enviar"
            action="#{userEditBean.submit()}" />
    </f:validateBean>
</h:form>
```

The managed bean:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserEditBean {

private static final String CURRENT_PAGE = "";
private static final String USER_LIST_PAGE = "userList";

//@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+", message =   "Email format is invalid.")
@Email(message = "Email format is invalid.")
private String email;


public String submit() {
    return CURRENT_PAGE;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

Notes:

- JSR 303 standard validations (@Null, @NotNull, ...) work perfectly, I can do email validation with a @Pattern as is showed [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple), but I want to know why other hibernate validator annotations don't work.
- Hibernate validator works perfectly if I try to insert a model with an invalid email in a property annotated with @Email, hibernate throws an exception in preinsert validation.
- I've tried annotating field or getter as is mentioned [here](http://www.edc4it.com/2011/12/07/jsf-2-0-and-jsr303-bean-validation-wierd-behaviour-or-standard/), neither of them worked.
- I've gone over the [hibernate validator reference integration chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#section-presentation-layer), but it just says you have to use the   tag to force validation.

Is it possible to use additional annotations from hibernate validator in a JSF bean or just the javax.validation.constraints.* standard ones? ([without using validator programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460373/how-can-i-programmatically-call-the-same-validator-that-runs-on-a-requestmethod))

**UPDATED: 2015-03-23: in response to BalusC answer:**

Glassfish 3.1.1 comes with hibernate-validator bundle and it's the same version I'm using, I can see this in server startup log:

```
2015-03-23T14:11:24.772+0100|Información: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.9 (-SNAPSHOT 20141218-0939 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.9@14083) para el contexto '/fwk4jsf'
2015-03-23T14:11:25.368+0100|Información: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final
```

And I also have the delegate="true" in my glassfish-web.xml, but it doesn't work either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish as being a Java EE container **already** ships with among others JSF and Bean Validation out the box. Upgrading them should be done by replacing the JARs in `/glassfish/modules` folder.

If this is not possible for some reason, and you really need to upgrade them via the webapp, then you need to instruct GlassFish to look in the webapp first for the libraries by adding the following entry to `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
<class-loader delegate="false" />
```

Otherwise GlassFish will still load them from own libs and/or classloading trouble will occur because there are duplicate classes with the same name, resulting in confusion and conflicts between libraries in an application with multiple classloaders, such as `instanceof` falsely returning `false` on an instance of a class loaded by another classloader having access to the duplicate library.

Comment: It didn't work, glassfish has the same hibernate validator version as I'm using in my app. I've edited the question.

Comment: Why are you supplying it along the webapp then?

Comment: Good point!, I had it because I need it to make the tests work, and I wanted to be sure it was the hibernate-validator standard and not one modified by glassfish developers. Setting the dependency to provided solved the problem and now the validations work. Thank you!.